# Account Balance 0 after 1 full day of GPU mining - GTX 770 - go-ethereum and ethminer

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, gpu, balances, ethminer

I am a little bit new in Ethereum Mining but I took a couple of days to read, study and understand the concept. I make my system (a clean one) Linux Ubuntu 14.04 ONLY for Ethereum Mining. I installed and ran successfully `go-ethereum` and `ethminer` and followed the tutorials to ensure I am mining.

The problem is that after a full day of mining my account balance is still 0.

I am doing GPU Mining with a nVIDIA GTX 770 with 2GB RAM

I will post here a part of my `go-ethereum` log just to make sure I am doing everything right. But after this some information:

How I ran those application

> 1 - geth account new
>
> 2 - ethminer -G
>
> 3 - geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain localhost 2>> geth.log &
>
> 4 - Sometime I also do a miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0]) in geth
>   console just to make sure that the mining is for my my account, I am
>   not sure if this works so please tell me.

geth.log

```
I0613 16:48:27.522828 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 1698729 with 15 txs & 0 uncles. Took 24.576085ms 
I0613 16:48:32.004443 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 15 txs in 13.837336ms. #1698729 [6a43bf6a / 6a43bf6a]  
I0613 16:48:32.005840 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 1698730 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 1.249741ms 
I0613 16:48:57.807846 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 1 txs in 3.698201ms. #1698730 [5e61b773 / 5e61b773]
```

And the ethminer shows the processing mining and stuff.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't succeed unless you are more patient and have a higher hashrate, please get some info about your rewards capabilities on a mining reward calculator, see [Does my mining situation sound normal?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5971/405)

Comment: Thank you, I joined a mining pool to see if I get coins faster, let's see but I think my GTX 770 is not worthy Eth Mining.

Comment: Be also aware that it will cost you more electricity than what you'll get as reward. Also consider that your hardware will age very fast.

Comment: Only one more question sir, I joined a mining pool so now I only start my `ethminer`. I start like this: - ethminer -F http://eth1.nanopool.org:8888/0xBC0d125d044b42Ba55a3c131cD6AfbedF71052BC -G

Is it the right way to start it with a mining pool? The `0xBC0d125d044b42Ba55a3c131cD6AfbedF71052BC` is my account address.

By the way, I calculated with you tool, it will give me 1 Ether per month, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes you're right, but again I advise you that you'd better buy some Ether from an exchange. Good luck and welcome to Ethereum!