# Is Mining with hashrate 100 KH/s on my computer same as 100 KH/s on cloud mining?

Tags: mining, hashrate, cloud-mining

I'm new to mining. I just started yesterday with a software: MinerGate. It shows that my computer is mining at about 100 KH/s. Contrary to the other guy [Does my mining situation sound normal?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5971/does-my-mining-situation-sound-normal) I can mine. So my question is rather about if my mining result can compare to the cloud mining below which offers same KH as me.

[image]

After about half a day it only mines 0.001 Ether.

This is very low: is it normal ?

I saw cloud mining offer of 100KH for 3.5$ does it mean this cloud mining will give me about the same low mining return?

Comment: Please see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5971/405

Comment: @NicolasMassart no it's not a duplicate the other can mine nothing whereas I can mine.

Comment: Both problems are due to your low hashrate. The other person's hashrate is just lower but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it looks like 100KH/s would earn about 0.0008ETH a day. You can find a mining calculator here: https://badmofo.github.io/ethereum-mining-calculator/ that will give you an idea of how much a given hash rate will earn. 100KH/s is a very low hash rate.

You should avoid cloud mining as they tend to be scams of one kind or another however if you want to rent hashing power for short amounts of time for testing you can rent directly from miners using nicehash.com under DaggerHashimoto